# Getting the Values from json::value using rest api c++

Tags: c++, json, rest

I am new to REST c++ api.

After using the GET Request, i have received the response from the server. The response is a json object. I receive using the following code snippet,

```html
client.request(methods::GET).then([](http_response response)
 {
  if (response.status_code() == status_codes::OK)
  {
   
   json::value jsonValue = response.extract_json().wait();
   return;
   
  }
 }).wait();
```

and the following is the json i have received

```html
{
  "StringTables": {
    "Day": "DD",
    "Month": "MM",
    "Year": "YY",
    "Hour": "HH",
    "Minute": "MM",
    "Seconds": "SS"
  },
  "TimeInfo": {
    "Start": 20,
    "End": 30
  }
}
```

How can i get the values from json::value? Like if i pass the key as "Day", i should be able to retrieve its value as "DD".

something like

```
string_t val = jsonValue[L"Day"].as_string();
```

is not possible. Can anyone help in accessing individual items (in a random fashion instead of sequential search) in json::value? I tried googling for 2 two days but couldn't get i wanted.

Comment: isn't it `jsonValue["StringTables"]["Day"]`?

Comment: i tried this string_t val = jsonValue[L"StringTables"][L"Day"].as_string(); but its crashing :(

Comment: Simple like : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj950082.aspx

Comment: @PaulRooney actually that worked.. i just replaced extract_json().wait() to extract_json().get() ... Thank You very much